# repeatedly construct and destroy context gives an error #1260

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

Under my project, I need to repeatedly construct and destroy context but it gives an error.

For example:

```
import zmq

for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    context = zmq.Context()
    data_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    data_socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5552")
    data_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
    context.destroy()
```

and it returns

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    data_socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5552")
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 580, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.connect
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Socket operation on non-socket
```

Comment: If your problem solved you can vote up to my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket options must be placed before the `.connect()` or `.bind()` method, and you can create a unit instance from `zmq.Context()`.

Try it:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context.instance()

for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    data_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    data_socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")
    data_socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5552")

context.destroy()
```

---

[**Your Answer**]:

However, if you want to do with your manner, you should close the socket in each iteration, so your code snippet will be:

```
import zmq

for i in range(100):
    ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
    sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
    sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5552')
    sock.close()  # Note
    ctx.destroy()
    print('ctx closed status: ', ctx.closed, ' iteration: ', i)
```

Out:

```
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 0)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 1)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 2)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 3)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 4)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 5)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 6)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 7)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 8)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 9)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 10)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 11)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 12)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 13)
('ctx closed status: ', True, ' iteration: ', 14)
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. If I want to do with first option, is there no need to close the socket?

Comment: You are welcome. No, but it depends on your code policy at all. On this example, both code snippet work fine.